# Sorting git timestamp in the shell

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, timestamp

I have a list of Git timestamps in the format `Mon Jan 1 01:01:01 2013 +0500`. I need sort them in the shell somehow and have no clue how to approach this. So far I've created two arrays - one for months and one for days.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

EDIT: This is not a git log that I'm going through, this is just a bunch of git timestamps that I have pulled out from different repos.

Comment: This is not a git log, just a list of different git timestamps from different git repos. What I'm asking is not a git feature. I'm asking how to sort these with bash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date` to convert to a format that's easier to sort, such as *epoch*. I'll assume you have a file called `dates.in`, with one date per line.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read d; do
    date -d "$d" +%s
done <dates.in | sort | \
while read d; do
    date -d "@$d"
done
```